# Stop xsd.exe from auto generate c++ header file from xsd schema

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xsd

I am using Visual Studio 2008.
I have xml files and corresponding xml schemas for validation.

When I modify any of schema files and save it VS automatically generate a header file,*.dll files and some garbage from it.
But I don't want this.
How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the schema file, click `Properties`. Then in "General", set `Exclude From Build` to "Yes".

Comment: I did it but IDE still generates the header file